# Can't get Blend 2015 to load package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, expression-blend, blend

I'm trying to extend Blend for VS2015, but I'm not able to get it to load my package.

When Blend tries to load the dll I've created I get

```
  <entry>
    <record>105</record>
    <time>2016/06/26 14:44:36.048</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{36D90EC2-5783-4439-8920-8AC00CF6890B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>106</record>
    <time>2016/06/26 14:44:36.056</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio Appid Stub</source>
    <description>CheckPackageSignature failed; invalid Package Load Key</description>
    <guid>{36D90EC2-5783-4439-8920-8AC00CF6890B}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>107</record>
    <time>2016/06/26 14:44:36.056</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Appid denied the loading of package</description>
    <guid>{36D90EC2-5783-4439-8920-8AC00CF6890B}</guid>
  </entry>
```

My problem is `CheckPackageSignature failed; invalid Package Load Key`, from what i read this doesn't apply anymore and there's no way for me to get a PLK because it seams to be obsolete since VS 2010 and all of the MS links are dead.

My package is really basic and I've added all the registry entries needed.

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[PluginRegistration("Blend extension", "Blend", typeof(DummyClass))]
[ProvideAutoLoad("11B8E6D7-C08B-4385-B321-321078CDD1F8")]
[Guid("36D90EC2-5783-4439-8920-8AC00CF6890B")]
public class ExtensionPackage:Package
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        TextLogger.Log("Initializing");
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can get a PLK for my package ?

If such a thing is not possible is there another way I can load custom package into Blend for Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, we do not support extending Blend. That said, if you do have a very compelling scenario that we think might benefit the greater community, we would love to help. Please reach out to me at unnir at Microsoft dot com with your specific usage that you think you will enable, and we can discuss this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, although your answer is correct, I'm still hoping for a workaround.